# Create formula to look and compare value against other and bring output yes/no

Tags: excel

What I am trying to achieve is to create a formula that when finds the word "Resolved" on column A, looks in same column but below for the word "New" and compares results of these rows with column B input (day). Basically will check if the Status Resolved and New happen in same day.

The output should be on column C2, C3 .. with result Yes or No, follows an example:

[image: Example/Screenshot below]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can it be assumed that any time there is an "investigation" the output will be "No", and that only when the cell immediately below "Resolved" is "New" is there the possibility of the output being "Yes"?

Comment: @Clif Hello! No, some times the flow is New -> Investigation -> Resolved and other times New -> Resolved (without investigation). I only want compare if the status Resolved happens in same day as the status New.  The events are listed from bottom to top as in the print.

Comment: So "New", "Investigation" and "Resolved" could all happen on the same day?

Comment: I should have asked: Can "New", "Investigation" and "Resolved" all happen on the same day?

Comment: @Clif , yes, they can happen in same day. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your two comments and the example, I believe that this formula, pasted into C2 and down, will get the results you are looking for:
`=IF(A2="Resolved",IF(AND(A3="New",B2=B3),"Yes",IF(AND(A4="New",B4=B2),"Yes","No")),"")`

Comment: thanks a lot :) it works like a charm!  I was already using h/vlookup but you made it easy and working. great!